# Vue FilePond bug with stylePanelLayout

Tags: vue.js, filepond

many of the FilePond property seem to not show an effect, but there are even some that render the component unusable. tried on codepen with the default example.

As soon as I add the following line:
            stylePanelLayout='compact circle'

to the component it doesn't react anymore to file selects

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <file-pond
            name="test"
            ref="pond"
            allow-multiple="true"
            accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
            v-bind:files="myFiles"
            stylePanelLayout='compact circle'

    />  </div>
</template>
```

you can try urself by adding this line to the demo from FilePond:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/KimGenius/Vue-FilePond-Live-Demo/tree/master/?from-embed

Answer (score 0):

please set `allow-multiple` to `false` to fix the issue. Might not be clear from the docs that this is necessary.